# When using built boost library in visual studio: libboost_regex-vc120-mt-sgd-1_59.lib(instances.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

### Problem

I am learning the boost library for future use in my x64 console application on windows. I tried the simplest example provided here:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#prepare-to-use-a-boost-library-binary

I want the boost library built to meet the following conditions:

1. for x64 platform. My console application is to deal with 3D data, so x64 is a must.
2. can be used in visual studio both in debug mode and release mode.
3. built as static library. My console application needs to be run on another computer.
4. can used in multithread. I need multithread to make make my program as fast as possible.

I read the instruction at that webpage and searched many other pages and tried many build command such as:

```
bjam --build-type=complete toolset=msvc-10.0 threading=multi link=static address-model=64
b2 variant=release --build-type=complete architecture=x86 address-model=64 stage
b2 runtime-link=static variant=release address-model=64
```

Finally, I built the small visual studio project successfully in x64|Debug mode. However, when I tried the Release mode I get errors like:

```
1>libboost_regex-vc120-mt-sgd-1_59.lib(instances.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '2' doesn't match value '0' in Temp.obj

1>libboost_regex-vc120-mt-sgd-1_59.lib(instances.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MTd_StaticDebug' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in Temp.obj

1>libboost_regex-vc120-mt-sgd-1_59.lib(regex.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '2' doesn't match value '0' in Temp.obj

1>libboost_regex-vc120-mt-sgd-1_59.lib(regex.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MTd_StaticDebug' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in Temp.obj
1>libboost_regex-vc120-mt-sgd-1_59.lib(regex_traits_defaults.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '2' doesn't match value '0' in Temp.obj

1>libboost_regex-vc120-mt-sgd-1_59.lib(regex_traits_defaults.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MTd_StaticDebug' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in Temp.obj

1>libboost_regex-vc120-mt-sgd-1_59.lib(static_mutex.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '2' doesn't match value '0' in Temp.obj

1>libboost_regex-vc120-mt-sgd-1_59.lib(static_mutex.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MTd_StaticDebug' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in Temp.obj

1>libboost_regex-vc120-mt-sgd-1_59.lib(w32_regex_traits.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '2' doesn't match value '0' in Temp.obj

1>libboost_regex-vc120-mt-sgd-1_59.lib(w32_regex_traits.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MTd_StaticDebug' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in Temp.obj

1>libboost_regex-vc120-mt-sgd-1_59.lib(regex_raw_buffer.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '2' doesn't match value '0' in Temp.obj

1>libboost_regex-vc120-mt-sgd-1_59.lib(regex_raw_buffer.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MTd_StaticDebug' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in Temp.obj

1>libcpmtd.lib(stdthrow.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '2' doesn't match value '0' in Temp.obj

1>libcpmtd.lib(stdthrow.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MTd_StaticDebug' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in Temp.obj

1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
```

### My Analysis

I'm using Visual Studio 2013. It seems the "sgd" in "libboost_regex-vc120-mt-sgd-1_59.lib(regex.obj)" indicates its a debug library. I searched the %BOOST_ROOT%\stage\lib. As with libboost_regex, I have:

```
"C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_59_0\stage\lib\libboost_regex-vc120-s-1_59.lib"
"C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_59_0\stage\lib\libboost_regex-vc120-sgd-1_59.lib"
"C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_59_0\stage\lib\libboost_regex-vc120-mt-1_59.lib"
"C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_59_0\stage\lib\libboost_regex-vc120-mt-s-1_59.lib"
"C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_59_0\stage\lib\libboost_regex-vc120-mt-sgd-1_59.lib"
"C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_59_0\stage\lib\libboost_regex-vc120-mt-gd-1_59.lib"
```

I didn't specify libboost_regex-vc120-mt-sgd-1_59.lib for visual studio, it selected by visual studio automatically. So, I think I either failed to built the real required lib or I need to set the project property somehow.

### My Question

1. How to make the small project built successfully in Release mode?
2. What the difference between b2 and bjam when building boost?

Comment: Have you tried changing the runtime library configuration for Release in `C/C++ >> Code Generation >> Runtime Library`?

Comment: Ok, I reviewed this post again and just solved the first question. It's a mistake. I used the same property sheet for Debug mode and Release mode. At the first trials, I set libboost_regex-vc120-sgd-1_59.lib in the additional dependencies setting for Debug mode. When I went to release mode, it seems visual studio checked the specified libboost_regex-vc120-sgd-1_59.lib first and tried to use but got errors. After I removed this setting, visual studio tried to find appropriate lib by itself, and probably found libboost_regex-vc120-s-1_59.lib.

Comment: Answer for question 2: http://www.boost.org/build/doc/html/bbv2/faq/names.html

Comment: It seems, libboost_regex-vc120-sgd-1_59.lib and libboost_regex-vc120-s-1_59.lib have similar points that make visual studio can't reject libboost_regex-vc120-sgd-1_59.lib automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to link release build against the LIBCMTD.

Comment: Why? what's  LIBCMTD used for?

Comment: libcmt is a CRT library. libcmtd is debug version of libcmt (note the 'd' at the end. It stands for 'debug'). I'll repeat once more "You DON'T want to link release build against libcmtd". Link it against the libcmt, or maybe you need to remove it completely, because boost might already have it.